# Allocating more memory in Python Spyder

Tags: python, memory, spyder

I am running a Python 2.7 script in Spyder that can run as long as I need, but I am getting a MemoryError. Short runs of this script do not do this, and I have no reason to believe that the run is substantially different as the runtime grows arbitrarily long. I'd like to go into Spyder's settings to allow more memory to be consumed, but I cannot find where to go in the settings.

Comment: can you post the script that you are referring to?

Comment: Why do you think this has anything to do with Spyder? What is the behavior you are seeing exactly?

Comment: I am getting a MemoryError if I set the run time too long. I need to edit the original post to highlight this.

Comment: Python continues to run until all system memory is consumed. This is the same for Spyder. You need to address the memory consumption of your program.

Comment: @roganjosh Until my PC's entire supply of memory is consumed?? Cause that is absolutely not what is happening when I get those MemoryErrors.

Comment: We need to see some representative code to help further. Also, there is no need to run the code through Spyder, launch it via python in terminal/cmd and see if you have the same issue.